# Hacer una consulta en Mysql para hacer una comparación de dos bases de datos y poder añadir los datos que son diferentes

Tags: sql

Tengo dos base de datos, una se llama es **base_vieja** en la cual quiero migrar los datos que tengo hacia **base_nueva** (actual), lo que pasa es que anteriormente ya había migrado las base de datos, pero ahora hay más datos que se agregaron y quiero agregaron esos que hay actualmente en **base_vieja**, los datos que quiero agregar son de dos tablas en especifico, la tabla de la **base_vieja** se llama **checadas1** y la tabla en la **base_nueva** se llama **transaction** las dos tienen cosas en común ya que son las checadas de los usuarios. El problema es que en la **base_vieja** hay '1355771' datos entonces quiero saber como puedo migrar los datos, que no están en la **base_nueva**

hice está consulta para hacer la comparación pero no me salen todos los registros, es por ello que pido de su ayuda

```
 SELECT 
    p.punch_time,
    c.checktime
    FROM base_nueva.transaction p
    RIGHT JOIN base_vieja.checadas c
    ON p.emp_code=c.pin;
```

espero me haya explicado bien

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles

Answer (score 0):

Regularmente se generan esas consultas con un left Join, y donde inicialmente va tu tabla vieja, y en el left Join tu tabla nueva, y validas que el campo validador en tu left sea nulo, con eso te retornara toda la información que no existe.

[image: Left Join Null]

Seria todo lo que existe en tu primer tabla excluyendo todo lo que existe en la segunda.

```
SELECT p.punch_time,
    c.checktime
FROM base_vieja.checadas p
    LEFT JOIN base_nueva.transaction c ON p.emp_code=c.pin
WHERE c.PIN IS NULL.
```

Te dejo un documento, donde explican esos movimientos en joins.
http://dbadixit.com/joins-en-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que describes quieres saber los datos que están en base vieja que no están en base nueva, te propongo la siguiente consulta

```
select * 
from base_vieja.checadas c
where c.pin not in (
                    select p.emp_no 
                    from base_nueva.transaction p
                   )
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es seleccionar todos los registros de la base vieja cuyo **emp_code** no este ya en la base nueva para ello empleamos una **subconsulta**, esta **subconsulta** obtiene todos los registros de la base nueva y estos registros son los que se verificarán para saber si ya existen o no en la otra tabla

Comment: Hola, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles